# LINQ Except() Method Does Not Work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have 2 `IList<T>` of the same type of object `ItemsDTO`. I want to exclude one list from another. However this does not seem to be working for me and I was wondering why?

```
IList<ItemsDTO> related = itemsbl.GetRelatedItems();
IList<ItemsDTO> relating = itemsbl.GetRelatingItems().Except(related).ToList();
```

I'm trying to remove items in `related` from the `relating` list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since class is a reference type, your `ItemsDTO` class must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for that to work.

Comment: I think it would be enough to override Equals alone. Why do you think you need to override GetHashCode?

Comment: @gprasant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c

Comment: `Except` uses `HashSets` internally.

Comment: @Magnus: Gosh, how did you know that? Anyways, for performance reasons?

Comment: For help on using a good algorithm for the hashcode see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/263400/468973) answer.

Comment: @gprasant No, a `HashSet` wont work at all if two equal objects return different hashcodes.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

The **default equality comparer** is going to be a reference comparison. So if those lists are populated independently of each other, they may contain the same objects from your point of view but different *references*.

When you use LINQ against SQL Server you have the benefit of LINQ translating your LINQ statement to a SQL query that can perform logical equality for you based on primary keys or value comparitors. With LINQ to Objects you'll need to define what **logical equality** means to `ItemsDTO`. And that means overriding `Equals()` as well as `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Except works well for value types. However, since you are using Ref types, you need to override `Equals` and `GethashCode`  on your `ItemsDTO` in order to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Apparently .NET thinks the items in one list are different from the same items in the other list (even though they are actually the same). This is what I did to fix it:

Have your class inherit [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), eg.

```
public class ItemsDTO: IEqualityComparer<ItemsDTO>
{
  public bool Equals(ItemsDTO x, ItemsDTO y)
  {
    if (x == null || y == null) return false;

    return ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x.Id == y.Id); // In this example, treat the items as equal if they have the same Id
  }

  public int GetHashCode(ItemsDTO obj)
  {
    return this.Id.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```